# Как организовать структуру программы?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

Есть учебный проект - локальная информационная система. Предполагаю реализовать его на .Net с помощью WPF. Поскольку это мой первый проект, я сразу же уперся в проблему. Каким образом реализовать интерфейс приложения? Таких окон как на скриншотах - 24. В WPF есть класс Page, но, насколько я понял, его используют для создания навигации как в браузерах. Каждая страница будет определена своим классом?

Comment: Можно реализовать все на одной странице, все зависит от ваших потребностей, и не обязательно что каждая функция - отдельная страница, и соответственно отдельная функция может быть в отдельном классе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если это учебный проект, который Вы хотите реализовать хорошо, и в полной мере насладиться возможностями `WPF`, я рекомендовал бы Вам почитать что такое паттерн MVVM. Не рекомендую на первых парах использовать библиотеки, такие как `Prism` и `LightMVVM`. Вначале просто реализуйте все ручками, поймете что где и как.

Следуя паттерну MVVM, Вы опишите свои модели, модели представлений (view models) и представления (views) и сможете довольно гибко все структурировать и кастомизировать.

Если Вы хотите все писать код-бихайндом, не использую никакие паттерны (MVC/MVVM). То я бы использовал обычный `Page`, как Вы и написали в вопросе. Каждая страница будет описана своим классом - своим представлением, при создании страницы Вы можете просто указывать какой ID сущности Вы хотите на данной странице отображать, собственно брать объект из далка.

Можно пойти еще более варварским путем и определить своеобразный холдер на `MainWindow`, описать ряд `UserControl`, представления для определенного типа сущностей, и пихать в этот холдер.

Comment: Спасибо, некое понимание теперь пришло

Answer (score 0):

Конкретно "все" окна вам писать нет необходимости.
Достаточно основного окна с минимальной логикой переключения между контролами и самих контролов. Тут вам поможет реализация [mvvm](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/22.1.php) вкупе с каким-нибудь фреймворком, типа [mvvm light toolkit](http://mvvmlight.net/).
Если умеете в английский и хотите увидеть, как это реализуется, то могу рекомендовать туториалы [этого парня](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vjldip84CXQ).

godspeed.

Comment: За ссылку спасибо